# using linspace in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

I want to create a vector which runs from 1 to 260 with increments of 360 between every whole number.

I can do this manually by: `y=linspace(1,2,360); y1=linspace(2,3,360);`... and so on.

By combining these I would have a vector which was 260*360=93600 long. However, there must be a easier way of doing this? preferably without a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can just do:

```
n=261;
linspace(1,n,(n-1)*360);
```

Answer (score 0):

And what about `y=(1:1/360:260)` ?

Or if you want to have exactly 360 elements between 1 and 2 (included) as it seems from your use of `linspace(1,2,360)` you could do `y=(1:1/359:260)`.

Also, your final vector would have less than 360*260 elements as you have to account for duplicates.